# Tracing MDX generated by Analysis Services in Excel

Tags: sql-server, mdx, ssas, cube

Is there a way to trace the actual MDX generated by querying a Cube in Excel, and get the actual MDX used ?

I've tried using SQL Profiler, and while that does return the MDX, it doesn't take into account the role that the connection is using (it's passed in a separate PropertySet).

I'm just wanting to get the MDX that the query is using, as it doesn't appear to be filtering correctly using different roles (but the same base MDX query).

**Update:** Ok, maybe I need to be a bit clearer. I'm trying to get the resulting query that is firing at the Cube, after the Role has been applied. 
SQL Profiler gives me the MDX, and the name of the role in a PropertySet, so is before the Role is applied.

**Update 2:**  In case it helps, this is an MDX query that I've been using to test the functionality.

```
select {[Measures].[Company Value]} on columns,
{[Dim Model].[Title Name].Members} on rows
from [DWHName]
```

Comment: Why do you want to see the restrictions being applied?

Comment: Because, as I say in the question, with two almost identical roles (the only difference being the member), one returns the correct filtered view, and one returns everything..

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try the following add-in from codeplex.  http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/  It just gives you what was sent to the OLAP server.  BEWARE though, it adds a bunch of extra mdx that does UI display.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't actually get what you're after.  The security role is a property of the connection or of the user running the query and the various restrictions put on the resultset are applied in the query engine.  So you never get to see what restrictions are applied (which, I suppose, could be a security issue in itself)

Comment: That's kind of what I was expecting. But, given that, how are you supposed to debug MDX queries, when using different roles? Sounds like you can't.

Comment: You can do that in the Browser tab of the Cube Designer in Visual Studio.  Click the Change User button and select the user you want to impersonate.  Or choose the roles you want to apply to the browsing.  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188087(v=SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I've properly understood your question, but it is possible to get the MDX generated by Excel using a macro to query the `PivotTable.MDX` property.

See [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2007/01/18/display-the-mdx-query-of-an-excel-2007-pivottable.aspx) for an example implementation.

Comment: I'd actually seen that, however, it gives the MDX before the security role is applied, so doesn't actually take into account the allowedset/deniedset that is part of the role. Effectively, this is the same as SQL Profiler, in that you get the MDX, but that remains the same, regardless of Role Membership. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand either. Are you saying that you want to see the results that role will see? (The MDX in the trace is exactly what was submitted, no?)

Have you tried executing the captured MDX through MDX Studio (where you can set the Role for your connection)?

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit. The issue is that I want to get the MDX after the role has been applied. I've tried running it through MDX Studio, and that, give the same results.

Comment: Hmm... I would have assumed that the MDX was always the same, but the results would vary depending on the role. I think I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: It's entirely possible I'm misunderstanding how Roles are applied to MDX. It's not something that is particularly well documented, anywhere.